# Find the parametrization for an arc tangent to the unit circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Given the unit circle(without boundary), and three points in the unit disk, $0,a,z$, where $a$ lies on the real axis, $z$ is some arbitrary complex number. I want to find the parametrization for the arc that passes $a$ and $z$ which intersects orthogonally with the unit disk.

My way of doing it is just suppose the equation of the arc is $(x-c)^2 +(y-d)^2= 1$, then solves the intersection point of it with the unit disk in terms of $c$ and $d$, then utilizes the orthogonal condition to solve $c$ and $d$. The formula is very nasty even for the intersection points, so I am not sure that this will work right. Are there simpler ways?

Comment: You cannot assume that the radius of the arc is $1$. Use $(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2=r^2.$ This gives you two equations, one for each of the points that are supposed to lie on the arc. The third equation originates from the orthogonal condition, it is $c^2+d^2=r^2+1^2.$ (If the circles intersect orthogonally, then the connection from the centers to the intersection point also intersect orthogonally and those connection together with the connection between the centers form a right triangle) Now you have three equations and three variables ($c$, $d$ and $r$). Can you continue from here?

Comment: So this will give me intersection points in terms of $c$ and $d$ right, then to solve $c$ and $d$ I need to use the orthogonal condition again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that the Möbius transformation
$$ T(w) = \frac{w-a}{1-\bar{a}w} $$
maps the unit circle to itself, $T(a)=0$. (Also, since $a$ is real, $\bar{a}=a$.) Möbius transformations preserve orthogonality, and we know that circular arcs through $0$ that are perpendicular to the unit circle are just radial.

So, we want a parametrisation of the radial line through $T(z)$. We then undo the transformation to get the original arc.

So, the radial line through the image of $z$ is $tT(z)$. So we have $$ T^{-1}(tT(z)) = \frac{tT(z)+a}{1+atT(z)} = \frac{t(z-a)+a(1-az)}{(1-az)+at(z-a)}. $$
This clearly passes through $a$ when $t=0$ and $z$ when $t=1$.

Comment: That is very neat!!!! thank you so much!

Comment: In the last equality, it should be 1-az

Comment: So it should. Thank you.